# Endermen won't attack Endermite [20w12a]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, for a map I'm making, I've set `doMobSpawning` to `false`, and I'm trying to create an Enderman farm using Endermites. I'm aware that Endermen will only attack a natural, pearl-spawned Endermite usually, but found via the Wiki that they have an NBT tag (namely, `PlayerSpawned`) that, when they have a value of `1`, will allow Endermen to attack it.

Here's my issue; it's not working. I've tried `1` and `1b` (since that is the only thing that will work on most occasions) and even tried my luck with `0` and `0b`, but no dice. I can't spawn an Endermite naturally because of `doMobSpawning` being `false`.

Is this `PlayerSpawned` NBT thing bugged, and should I submit a report seeing this is a snapshot version? Or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you summoned the endermite with that tag or have you changed its NBT while it already existed?

Comment: It works fine for me in all cases, even when changing it to 1 after the enderman already exists. Are you sure that there is a line of sight and a valid path to walk for the enderman? Have you tried just putting one next to the other? What about a completely newly generated world, is it the same there?

Comment: It would be the line of sight issue, I just realized. I overestimated their sight and path finding and apparently was one block higher than they would actually see. I'm going to put the answer down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some testing, I've found it's a line-of-sight issue with the Endermen. Apparently my Endermite was just one block above their sight, so they didn't actually see the Endermite at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're typing the command in wrong. Try this command, this is how I did it:

```
/summon minecraft:endermite ~ ~ ~ {PlayerSpawned:true}
```

Comment: I think its 1b, aint it?

Comment: thanks, but the issue was already resolved. it was a line of sight issue, and apparently the endermite was a single block higher than i thought their line of sight was.